# Check if accordion already applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using jQuery UI and I want to check if `accordion` is already applied to some element. In this case I will refresh it, else I will apply it. I want something like this

```
        if (already_applied) {
            $('#element').accordion('refresh');
        }
        else {
            $('#element').accordion(
                {
                    header: '> div > h3',
                    collapsible: true,
                    active: true,
                    autoHeight: false
                }
            );
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ($('#element').hasClass('ui-accordion')) {
    $('#element').accordion('refresh');
}
else {
    $('#element').accordion({
        header: '> div > h3',
        collapsible: true,
        active: true,
        autoHeight: false
    });
};​
```